# ANN different results for same train-test sets

Tags: matlab, neural-network, classification

I'm implementing a neural network for a supervised classification task in MATLAB.

I have a training set and a test set to evaluate the results.
The problem is that every time I train the network for the same training set I get very different results (sometimes I get a 95% classification accuracy and sometimes like 60%) for the same test set.

Now I know this is because I get different initial weights and I know that I can use 'seed' to set the same initial weights but the question is what does this say about my data and what is the right way to look at this? How do I define the accuracy I'm getting using my designed ANN? Is there a protocol for this (like running the ANN 50 times and get an average accuracy or something)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your test set is large enough compared to the training set (e.g. 10% of the overall data) and check it regarding diversity. If your test set only covers very specific cases, this could be a reason. Also make sure you always use the same test set. Alternatively you should google the term *cross-validation*.

Furthermore, observing good training set accuracy while observing bad test set accuracy is a sign for *overfitting*. Try to apply regularization like a simple L2 weight decay (simply multiply your weight matrices with e.g. 0.999 after each weight update). Depending on your data, [Dropout](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.0580.pdf) or L1 regularization could also help (especially if you have a lot of redundancies in your input data). Also try to choose a smaller network topology (fewer layers and/or fewer neurons per layer).

To speed up training, you could also try alternative learning algorithms like [RPROP+, RPROP- or RMSProp](https://class.coursera.org/neuralnets-2012-001/lecture/preview) instead of plain backpropagation.

Comment: Hi schreon, thanks for your comment, the thing is that I'm aware that the test data is not optimal for the train data (they have different sources), but I still want to present some sort of classification accuracy for an ANN trained on that training set and I can't since the results are different each time... I will take a lkook at those alternatives you've suggested, looks interesting. Thanks!

Comment: Could you give some more information on how many data samples you have available and what kind of data you are dealing with? In fact it is good to have test data differing from your training data. The more different your test data are from your training data, the more convincing your test accuracy is regarding generalization performance. But within your test set you should have a certain diversity of cases. Moreover: How do you determine the point of convergence right now?

Comment: It's a a bit complicated to explain on my prob so I will give an example. Suppose I'm trying to classify between green apples and oranges based on the feature "color". I trained an ANN that classifies between both, and works good for an apples/orange test set. Now I believe that the same difference occurs between green tomatoes and bananas, so I'm trying to use the same ANN trained for apples/oranges for a tomatoes/bananas test set. The problem is that I understandably get different classification accuracy each time I train my ANN. Hope I'm clear enough. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your ANN is not converging to the optimal set of weights. Without further details of the ANN model, I cannot pinpoint the problem, but I would try increasing the number of iterations.

Comment: I thought about this option, but I believe it does converges to the optimal set of weights because for the training set it receives very good classification results. Maybe they can be obtained in several different sets of weights, some work good for my test set and some not? Thanks again...